# Publicly sharing an iCal calendar to allow web viewing

Tags: macos, icloud, ical

When using iCal in Snow Leopard, I shared a calendar.

I had two options for this - either a privately shared, editable calendar, or a publicably shared, view-only calendar. I used the latter option, and was provided with two URLs - one of which allowed my friends and colleagues to subscribe (via their own iCal or other software) and the other of which was an ordinary web address, that allowed them to view my calendar in their web browser.

It's this latter type that I'm now trying to set up in iCloud, but I can't seem to find an option to do so - neither in iCloud itself nor on iCal running on Lion.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

In iCal, click the "Calendars" button in the upper-left corner, just under the traffic light. Right-click on the calendar you want to share, then select "Share Calendar..." This will open a new dialog, allowing the choice you mentioned between sharing read-only with everyone, or editable with invitees; make your selection and hit "Share".

Once the calendar is shared, again click the Calendar button and right-click the calendar you just shared, this time selecting "Copy URL to Clipboard".

(There's also a "Stop Sharing" option, in case you ever change your mind.)

Comment: How did you manage to display this URL (webcal://p04-www.icloud.com/ca/subscribe...) to display correctly in a browser?

Comment: @patrix webcal:// addresses aren't meant to be viewed in a browser. They are rather for subscribing to a given calendar within a calendar app (such as iCal).

Comment: iCal gave me two URLs, one which began webcal:// as in your example above, but another that began http:// and could be viewed in a browser. I've tried just changing the beginning of the webcal:// address to http:// but that doesn't help!

Comment: @Ben It seems that you can only get an https:// address (which requires the viewer to sign in to iCloud) if you're sharing privately, and a webcal:// address if sharing publicly.

Comment: I'm guessing (but don't know for sure) that the publicly viewable page was a function of MobileMe that hasn't been implemented in a similar manner with iCloud.

Comment: @nmpeterson: I'm Award of that but the question asked for a web browser option and I was wondering whether you found a way to accomplish that. Oh well, let's hope for an upgrade.